# bash function argument and pipeline at the same time

Tags: bash

I wrote a short super simple script (question from exam) that gets as a parameter `log.txt` file (just a file with lots of dates), and creates a `temp.txt` that contains some sorted values -- I have this code line:

```
cat $1 | date_isolate | sort | uniq | create_relevant $1
```

Where `$1` should be the `log.txt` argument.

The question: my function `create_relevant` -- it gets standard input via pipeline and I want it to get another argument which is `log.txt` - how do I mark each argument in the function?  Is it `$1` for the pipeline and `$2` for `log.txt` or just `$1` for `log.txt` and I read from pipeline via `read`?

Comment: The pipeline has nothing to do with arguments.  It redirects stdin and stdout.  This is basic Unix stuff.

Comment: Can  you show the whole function, and what the expected inputs and outputs are?

Comment: BTW, `cat $1` is bad form -- it's unnecessarily creating an extra subprocess, such that `date_isolate` is forced to read from a pipe rather than straight from your `log.txt`; this is both a tiny bit slower to run, and means that `date_isolate` is more limited in how it can interact with the file: a pipe can only be read front to back, a regular file can be jumped around in, reread, etc. Better to run `date_isolate <"$1" | sort -u | create_relevant "$1"`

Comment: ...and note the quotes -- try testing with `"log file.txt"` instead of `log.txt` and you'll see why they're necessary.

Comment: thanks Charles! it was very useful info for understanding bash for me!

Comment: BTW -- be careful using the same filename for input and output. A pipeline starts all components at once -- that means that if `create_relevant` truncates the file named in the argument it's passed as `$1`, then the first part of the pipeline may not have anything there to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since `create_relevant` gets its input from *STDIN*, the most consistent interface would be to send its output to *STDOUT*.  So the whole pipeline would look something like:

```
date_isolate < "$1" | sort -u | create_relevant > temp.txt
```

Or, avoid `temp.txt` with this lazy version:

```
date_isolate < "$1" | sort -u | create_relevant | sponge "$1"
```

([`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is a util which prevents "*$1*" from being overwritten until it should be.)